# How to Mock class with other class in Python unittest

Tags: python, unit-testing, class, testing, mocking

I'm trying to mock a class in python with another class using unittest but the `unittest.patch` creates an instance from the mock class and replaces the original class with it. Here is the description

The Origin class is located in the file: `src/libutil/util.py`

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.a = self.g()
        self.c = "parent"

    def g(self):
        return "HI from parent"
```

The mock class is located in the file `tests/libraries/mocks/util.py`

```py
class B(A):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
    
    def g(self):
        return "Hi from child"
```

I'm mocking that using unittest as follows:

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
def mock_util():
    from tests.libraries.mocks.util import B

    with mock.patch('libutil.util.A', new_callable=B, create=False) as util_mock:
        yield util_mock
```

The problem is that the patch creates an instance from class B and replaces class A with it instead of replacing class A with class B itself. When I use `a = libutil.util.A()` that doesn't work and throws `TypeError: 'B' object is not callable`.

Can you help me in mocking class A with class B itself? Please note that the usage here is a simplified example.

Comment: Why do you want the mock to inherit from what it's mocking? The entire point is that it should *simulate* the functionality, not rely on it. Also, please read [mre] and show: an example broken test, and a [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) corresponding error message. We should be able to copy and paste the code from the question into appropriate source files **without adding or changing anything**, and see the exact problem **directly**.

Comment: I have to inherit the original class since there are a lot of attributes and functionalities in the logic I use in the origin class.